# Qt Quick Layouts: distribute row items horizontally?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am using a combination of `ColumnLayout` with nested `RowLayout`s:

[image]

and I'm trying to distribute items horizontally, so that the left edge of every row's first item lines up, and the right edge of every row's last item lines up, with a uniform spacing in between.

As an additional constraint, I want the window to automatically adjust its size to fit its contents, and I believe I achieved this by propagating `implicitWidth`/`implicitHeight` from root downwards.

I used `Rectangle`s and `Repeater`s to keep the code short:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: rootRect.implicitWidth
    height: rootRect.implicitHeight
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    readonly property var items: [
        [[120, 80, 'red'], [100, 80, 'green'], [170, 40, 'blue']],
        [[60, 120, 'yellow'], [140, 80, 'orange'], [60, 100, 'cyan']],
        [[150, 100, 'purple'], [100, 80, 'blue'], [170, 40, 'orange']],
    ]

    Rectangle {
        id: rootRect
        // achieve a padding of 5
        implicitWidth: columnLayout.implicitWidth + 10
        implicitHeight: columnLayout.implicitHeight + 10

        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            anchors.centerIn: parent // for above padding

            Repeater {
                model: items

                Item {
                    id: row
                    implicitWidth: rowLayout.implicitWidth //[*]
                    //[*] Layout.fillWidth: true
                    implicitHeight: rowLayout.implicitHeight
                    readonly property var rowItems: modelData

                    RowLayout {
                        id: rowLayout
                        //[*] Layout.fillWidth: true

                        Repeater {
                            model: rowItems

                            Rectangle {
                                width: modelData[0]
                                height: modelData[1]
                                color: modelData[2]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I try (e.g. any combination of adding/removing the lines with `//[*] ...`), I cannot get the items to distribute horizontally.

It looks like a non-trivial operation, as the row with maximum size should do what it is currently doing, while the other rows should simply set their size to follow, and distribute their items accordingly... or perhaps I overlook some property of Qt Quick Layouts.

Note: I'm using layouts and not positioners, as in reality I'm laying out Qt Quick Controls that could benefit from being resized by a layout.

EDIT: when I add an item to style rows, it breaks again: [try it online](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer.
This solution is based on the QML style in your question with minor tweaks.

I made use of the `Frame` component. `Frame`, if you haven't used it before, is a very convenient component for wrapping your contents with padding. So, instead of `Rectangle`-`ColumnLayout`. It's `Frame`-`ColumnLayout`. This is really useful because it allows you to delete the unnecessary pixel math that you had in both your `Rectangle` and your `ColumnLayout`.

I used `Item` to solve your horizontal alignment problem. I did this by setting the `Item`'s `Layout.preferredWidth` as well as setting `Layout.fillWidth: true`. Both properties, when used together will cause the `Item` to grow in size and distribute the spacing equally horizontally.

Finally, I do some anchoring to make sure the `Rectangle` inside the `Item` is anchored left, middle, or right.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#444" }
    readonly property var items: [
        [[120, 80, 'red'], [100, 80, 'green'], [170, 40, 'blue']],
        [[60, 120, 'yellow'], [140, 80, 'orange'], [60, 100, 'cyan']],
        [[150, 100, 'purple'], [100, 80, 'blue'], [170, 40, 'orange']],
    ]
    Frame {
        background: Rectangle { }
        ColumnLayout {
            Repeater {
                model: items
                RowLayout {
                    id: rowLayout
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Repeater {
                        model: modelData
                        Item {
                            Layout.preferredWidth: modelData[0]
                            Layout.preferredHeight: modelData[1]
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Rectangle {
                                anchors.centerIn: index === 1 ? parent : undefined
                                anchors.right: index === 2 ? parent.right : undefined
                                width: modelData[0]
                                height: modelData[1]
                                color: modelData[2]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

[image: final-result]

Here's a [demo link](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAGP3icnVNNj5swEL3nV4y2By5RFCK2rVhFPexq25V66ObSA+LghQmx1thoYpqiiv9eG0NCWJJs9kn58Jvn5+GN4XmhSMOzfi558jrhR8vZvZKalNgO+Z+sUqXeTn6xDOHfBAxeWPKakSplGsIKE81kJkwNEiUUhXDzKQiCG6gbLSFLlRQVFKQKJF3BH0bANebbEKJGYhFF/mI+ha/m4xGmXjyFyJ93TEaI0nFfzDqw3Iso0Yvjac/is+EbG69CIdTO7Qg6F0WmUWzIRmntvaRicmDj3+6rRUmFwEE37uSjZjrr1iduvh+J5V1k52Kr94p7JcpcusR7Gy1WWCDTSAPaIlcpitBl+qY4bKIPd9BszYX4zVO9CUFTiaPSE723E/cEzzb6O7HKuwNiKS/NcBe39ajVSu1Gn7APbo6hTndStXNNF4xQ6lmzOqk9k18fbZbNzwPT7Kz4ySR+wc+ijbkgXCOZy91mvT8jmsdXe/xAm3jfxH+3yXvm3Udv3he1FkwmG0XbWWKmgvQkzdWUKf6F5XIJPnxr5wUhmNuEay4xvcqW3JMfPBd7T1e72nn3gYFYbD4yBIv2tTnsW1zeN/4yXa6OV96yx8xh5f7Vk/o/YXN3SQ==) for your followup question. Each RowLayout is stylized with a Frame.

Comment: In my real example, I have a `Rectangle` to style rows, so I've made an error while creating a MCVE. I took your solution, and I insert a `Frame` to wrap rows, but then the items won't fill the row space anymore (see link in updated question). How to fix that? Perhaps I should ask a new question

Comment: That's because the RowLayout parent is now a Frame. i.e. the parent is no longer a ColumnLayout. So you need to replace `Layout.fillWidth: true` with `width: parent.width`. I've added an additional link in my answer reflecting this.

Comment: Also, for your Frame you only need to set `Layout.fillWidth: true` so that it will get its width from the parent ColumnLayout. You can omit the `Layout.fillHeight: true` because the `Frame` will, intuitively derived the height from the children.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `Layout.fillWidth` on the items inside the layout as well otherwise the layout uses the set width to layout the items. I've used an `Item` around the actual `Rectangle` to achieve what you want and being able to set `Layout.fillWidth` on it.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: columnLayout.implicitWidth + 10
    height: columnLayout.implicitHeight + 10
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    readonly property var items: [
        [[120, 80, 'red'], [100, 80, 'green'], [170, 40, 'blue']],
        [[60, 120, 'yellow'], [140, 80, 'orange'], [60, 100, 'cyan']],
        [[150, 100, 'purple'], [100, 80, 'blue'], [170, 40, 'orange']],
    ]

    ColumnLayout {
        id: columnLayout
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Repeater {
            model: root.items

            RowLayout {
                Repeater {
                    id: nestedRepeater
                    model: modelData

                    Item {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.minimumWidth: modelData[0]
                        Layout.minimumHeight: modelData[1]

                        Rectangle {
                            id: rect
                            property bool leftItem: index === 0
                            property bool rightItem: index === (nestedRepeater.count - 1)
                            property bool centerItem: !rect.leftItem && !rect.rightItem

                            anchors.centerIn: rect.centerItem ? parent : undefined
                            anchors.left: rect.leftItem ? parent.left : undefined
                            anchors.right: rect.rightItem ? parent.right : undefined

                            width: modelData[0]
                            height: modelData[1]
                            color: modelData[2]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

This version fixes the center alignment issue mentioned in my comment below.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: columnLayout.implicitWidth + 10
    height: columnLayout.implicitHeight + 10
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    readonly property var items: [
        [[120, 80, 'red'], [100, 80, 'green'], [170, 40, 'blue']],
        [[60, 120, 'yellow'], [140, 80, 'orange'], [60, 100, 'cyan']],
        [[150, 100, 'purple'], [100, 80, 'blue'], [170, 40, 'orange']],
    ]

    ColumnLayout {
        id: columnLayout
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Repeater {
            model: root.items

            RowLayout {
                Repeater {
                    id: nestedRepeater
                    model: modelData

                    Item {
                        id: item
                        property bool leftItem: index === 0
                        property bool rightItem: index === (nestedRepeater.count - 1)
                        property bool centerItem: !item.leftItem && !item.rightItem

                        Layout.fillWidth: item.centerItem
                        Layout.minimumWidth: modelData[0]
                        Layout.maximumWidth: (item.leftItem || item.rightItem) ? modelData[0] : -1
                        Layout.minimumHeight: modelData[1]

                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            width: modelData[0]
                            height: modelData[1]
                            color: modelData[2]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The distance between red-green and green-blue in the upper row isn't the same. I'm trying to fix that. This is probably due to the weight applied to the surrounding `Item`.

Comment: Perfectionist :-) I would have been accepted also the first answer, but didn't have yet the time to study/try it. Now looking at it again I realize the wrapper `Item` is being resized to fill, and its children simply snapped to left/center/right. However, wouldn't the resizing of `Item` interfere with its children (a Qt Quick Control) sizing policy?

Comment: I was thinking to a different solution, where the `RowLayout`'s `spacing` is computed dynamically as (the `width` of its parent minus the sum of the `implicitWidth` of its children) divided by (number of children - 1)... could it ever work?

Comment: i.e. under `RowLayout`: `spacing: { var s = row.width; for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { s -= children[i].implicitWidth } s = s / (children.length - 1); return s }` but it generates a binding loop over `implicitWidth`...

Comment: If you want to calculate the size/layout yourself I would recommend using positioners over layouts.

Comment: At least that is what we do for responsive layouts in QtDS property editor and it also uses QtQuick.Controls. For this "precise" layouting I just don't like to rely on the layout capabilities and logic of Layouts.